# Group By Month between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table that lists all employees and their respective start and end dates

I want to be able to count the number of active employees in each month. Is there a way to do this via a single query (eg groupBy) rather than generating multiple queries for each month?

```
    =================================
    Employee ID   | StartDt      | EndDt
    123           | 01 Feb 2022  |  
    234           | 01 jan 2022  | 28 Feb 2022
    456           | 01 dec 2021  | 28 Feb 2022
```

As an example, the table above should return:

- Dec 2021: 1
- Jan 2022: 2
- Feb 2022: 3
- Mar 2022: 1
- Apr 2022: 1

Comment: Are you sure you mean `Dec 2022` and not `Dec 2021`?

Comment: oops! Fixed. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a calendar and join to that:

```sql
WITH calendar (month) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(min_startdt, LEVEL - 1)
  FROM   (
    SELECT MIN(startdt) AS min_startdt,
           MAX(COALESCE(enddt, SYSDATE)) AS max_enddt
    FROM   employees
  )
  CONNECT BY LEVEL - 1 <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(max_enddt, min_startdt)
)
SELECT c.month,
       COUNT(e.employee_id)
FROM   calendar c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e
       ON (e.startdt <= c.month AND (c.month <= e.enddt OR e.enddt IS NULL))
GROUP BY
       c.month
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (Employee_ID, StartDt, EndDt ) AS
SELECT 123, DATE '2022-02-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 234, DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-02-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, DATE '2021-12-01', DATE '2022-02-28' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | MONTH | COUNT(E.EMPLOYEE_ID) |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 1 |
> | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 3 |
> | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 | 1 |
> | 2022-04-01 00:00:00 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fb1e2d08b96ed2b1510115f2265e8a50)*